# ST_MakeLine returns Unsupported geometries not rendered in geometry viewer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am trying to run a ST_MakeLine query that will return the shortest distance between given coordinates
The code is as follows:

```sql
SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom)  as test
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM pgr_fromAtoB('roads2_noded',73.1789,33.5183,73.1768,33.5191)
      ORDER BY seq
     ) As route
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

it's clear that the result does not show null. But when I view it in the Geometry Viewer, it gives the following message:

[image]

Can someone tell me what this message means and how can I find a workaround to this problem?
The geometry type of my roads shapefile is MULTILINESTRING.

St_AsText (route.geom) shows the following result:

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(route.geom)) FROM (SELECT *FROM pgr_fromAtoB('roads2_noded',73.1789,33.5183,73.1768,33.5191)
      ORDER BY seq
     ) As route
```

[image]

Using simple Select from pgr_fromAtoB gives:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_fromAtoB('roads2_noded',73.1789,33.5183,73.1768,33.5191) ORDER BY seq
```

[image]

The roads2_noded is the roads shapefile I am working on shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the result of `ST_AsText(route.geom)`?

Comment: ST_AsText shows nothing...No Column entry at all. I have posted a picture in the question above as well

Comment: okay. can you show the result of `SELECT * FROM pgr_fromAtoB('roads2_noded',33.5183,73.1789,33.5191,73.1768) ORDER BY seq`? What does it provide?

Comment: I've added the results to the question

Comment: thank you, what is `'roads2_noded'`? Can you show it?

Comment: I have added the roads2_noded shapefile to the question as well

Comment: you cannot use multilinestrings for pg_routing functions. use st_dump to break them up into single linestrings

Comment: @ziggy How do I apply st_dump on my entire table?

Comment: before you create the network -- create a new table and make the geoms linestrings then use the pg routing functions to create the network tables

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pg_Routing functions cannot be used for MultiLineStrings. Therefore, first create a new table with all the data entries of the roads2 table. Then add the columns of roads2 to the new table. For example id, sub_id, name, distance ,geom etc. Then use the following query to convert the MultiLineString geometry of roads2 to LineString.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(linestring,4326) USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1);
```

After that add the geom column of roads2 to the new table. After that apply the road network and topology queries i.e. pgr_nodeNetwork and pgr_createTopology and create the function pgr_fromAtoB
Then run the ST_MakeLine query:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom)  as test
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM pgr_fromAtoB('my_table_noded',73.1789,33.5183,73.1768,33.5191)
      ORDER BY seq
     ) As route
```

The result will show the geometry:

[image]